# Xcode's "clean" cleans configurations that were never built

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, build

After building my project in debug configuration, I can find the following directory structure within the `DerivedData` folder:

```
$ ls /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator   Debug-watchsimulator
```

This indicates that only the debug configuration was built.

Now, after I hit "clean" in Xcode (SHIFT + COMMAND + K), I see the following structure:

```
$ ls /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator       Distribution-watchsimulator
Debug-watchsimulator        Release-iphonesimulator
Distribution-iphonesimulator    Release-watchsimulator
```

In fact, looking at the report navigator in Xcode, I can see that all of my targets are cleaned three times (once for debug, release and distribution) although I never built using the release or distribution configuration.

Is this a misconfiguration of the targets or intended behavior? Is it possible to make Xcode clean only those configurations that were actually built? My project is quite big and cleaning everything three times takes a considerable amount of time which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Why are you cleaning so often?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I keep running into situations where Xcode fails to link the compiled sources after changing Swift code. Only cleaning and recompiling works for me when that happens.